# Django caching and spatial queries

Tags: django, caching, memcached, geospatial

This is a simple question and I'm not sure where to look up for the answer.

Will Django honor any (or specifically memcached) caching strategy while running spatial queries? Or it will hit the database everytime?

I have a certain process that I need to run that will be a bulk insert that does around 4 spatial queries for each inserted object and I would really really want to have all of those objects cached in memory.